# Where to place 2.5 inch HDD in Be quiet silent base 800?

Tags: hard-drive

I just bought a new tower called "Be quiet Silent Base 800". They indicate that it is possible to install  4 2.5 inch HDDs in it. I am unable to determine where/how to install 2.5" HDs.

Comment: You haven't looked very far. Look in page 8 of the manual for a complete diagram http://www.bequiet.com/volumes/PDM/_series/slntbse800/slntbse800_mn_en.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its in the [manual](http://www.bequiet.com/en/case/546), page 59, one mounts in each 3.5mm cage, upside down on top of the cage  2 mount behind the motherboard bay on specific trays

Comment: thanks, solved my problem. I looked everywhere to find it...